# Linear search in the sorted array with the increment of 2 instead of 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a task to implement the `contains` function **using linear search** that works on the sorted array. I've done it in this way:

```
function contains(a, e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {   
    if (e === a[i]) {
      return true;
    } else if (e < a[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

However, for the task there's a note:

> We can make further improvements by incrementing the index at a faster
>   rate (say, 2). This will reduce the number of comparisons for
>   searching in the sorted list.

I don't understand how we can do that because we can't skip elements. The only thing that comes to mind is to check current index and previous index:

```
if (e === a[i] || e === a[i-1]) {
```

but that's probably not what the author meant. Any ideas?

The example is in the JavaScript language. However I'm interested in the generic solution not specific to any language so you can treat it as a pseudo code.

Comment: In which language are you programming? Is the code you show in that language or is it pseudo-code? Do you want a language-agnostic solution? Please add the correct language-tag or the `language-agnostic` tag.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'm interested in the generic solution, but the code in JavaScript, I added the tag

Comment: Have you considered binary search?

Comment: @ApoorvJoshi, yeah, thanks, the task is specific to linear search. I added that information to the question

Comment: "_we can't skip elements_", why not? Just increment `i` inside the body of the loop.

Comment: @Teemu, can you show a reliable solution that guarantees correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array contains numbers, you can skip every second element if you don't check if the elements are equal, but if you check if the element you search is bigger than the one at your current index.

In every loop you check `if array[i] < a`. If it is smaller than `a` you continue, else you take the value at `i-1` and check if this is the value you are looking for. Because the array is sorted, you know at this point that the only position your searched value can be is at `i-1`.

For example:

```
Array: [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 10]
a: 5

array[0] < 5 -> true
array[2] < 5 -> true
array[4] < 5 -> false
```

at this point you know that if your value exists in the array, it is between array[2] and array[4], because we know that `array[2] < 5 < array[4]`

So now you check:

```
array[3] == 5
```

If this returns true, your array contains the value, else it doesn't

```
function contains2(a, e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2) {
    if (a[i] < e) {
      continue;
    } else {
      if (a[i-1] === e) {
        return true;
     } else if (a[i] === e) {
       return true;
     } else {
       return false;
     }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is the implementation. In the JSBin linked below, you can see a comparison of both functions. I added a log to count how often each loop runs. In the given example, your functions needs to run 8 times, because it compares the search value with the values `array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4], array[5], array[6], array[7]` until it gives the result. 
The second functions skips every second entry, so it just compares the search value to `array[0], array[2], array[4], array[6], array[8]` and then find it at `array[7]`. That's why it needs less comparisons.

https://jsbin.com/vojahoyaju/edit?js,console

Comment: thanks, can you show the implementation, I don't see how that is better than the solution with the increment of 1

Comment: thanks, I'm wondering if it makes sense to increment index even more?

Comment: @Maximus incrementing it even more would normally not be better, because if you have multiple entries between the current one and the last one you checked, you'll need to do multiple comparisons as well. This solutions works, because if you know that a[4] < e and a[6] > e than a[5] = e. But if you only know that a[4] < e and a[9] > e than e could either be a[5], a[6], a[7] or a[8] - there is no way to tell, unless you do more comparisons. So no, if you want to do it this way you shouldn't increment it more.

Comment: `contains2([1, 2], 2)` returns `false`. Also you have `console.log(num)` where `num` is not defined

Comment: Also, the explanation "check if array[i] <= a. If it is smaller than a you continue" looks very confused - clearly, `array[i] < a` is meant here.

Comment: @NilsSchlüter, can you please make your code correct so that there's no confusion

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, I will add my own answer that incorporates the same idea as both previous answers.

Assume the problem is to find `key` in `array` using linear search, i.e. a for loop for `i` from `0` to `array.length-1`. Normally one would do that by evaluating `array[i] == key` for each `i`. However, it is possible to skip every second element in the search by using inequality instead of equality.
The trick is to evaluate `array[i] < key` instead of `array[i] == key`. If this condition is false, then it holds that if key is in the array, it's either in positions `array[i-1]` or `array[i]`.

Additionally, the last element of the array may have to be checked explicitly depending on whether the array length is even or odd.

A runnable and tested code is provided below.

```js
function contains(array, key) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {   
    if (array[i] < key) {
      // continue search
      continue;
    }
    // compare with the current element
    if (array[i] === key) {
      return true;
    }
    // compare with the skipped element
    if (i > 0 && array[i - 1] === key) {
      return true;
    }
    // it's neither the current nor the skipped element
    return false;
  }
  // for even-sized arrays, check the last element
  if (i < array.length + 1) {
    if (array[i - 1] === key) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(contains([10, 20, 30, 40], 10)); // true
console.log(contains([10, 20, 30, 40], 20)); // true
console.log(contains([10, 20, 30, 40], 30)); // true
console.log(contains([10, 20, 30, 40], 40)); // true
console.log(contains([10, 20, 30, 40], 25)); // false
```

In a similar vein, this idea could be generalized to skip two, three, ... `n` elements. Then `n-1` explicit checks for equality should be added to the bpdy of the loop. Still, for large enough arrays binary search will always be better, as binary search does *O(log n)* comparisons, while all of the methods above do *O(n)* comparisons: skipping over some elements improves the performance by a constant factor, but not asymptotically.

Comment: Since accepted answer's op doesn't seem to wish for correctness, I took the liberty of doing it. Your point started to grow on me. I wouldn't edit your answer though, but would suggest you remove the part about the (now correct) accepted answer. Thanks for your actions here.

Comment: @kfx, is the time complexity stil `logN` with this implementation?

Comment: No, it's linear

Answer (score 1):

```
function contains(a, e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i+= 2) {   
    if (e === a[i]) {
      return true;
    } else if (e < a[i]) 
    {
      //now compare with skipped element
       if(e == a[i-1]) return true; 
       else return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks, do you see how this is better than the original implementation?

Comment: `contains2([1, 2], 2)` returns `false`.

Comment: @Maximus this buggy, but still much better than the accepted answer which is full of problems. I recommend accepting this is it's fixed

Comment: @kfx, I upvoted this answer. The actual implementation is not interesting for me. I was curios in the idea. The other answer explained the idea.

Comment: @Maximus maybe I'm feeling cranky today, but I think answers with invalid code should not be upvoted on SO. I don't have a reference for this at the moment, but given how SO is often used for finding and copying code, the code that is here should be correct.

Comment: @kfx, yeah, I don't know. I mean I never copy/paste from SO without understanding what's going on, and I don't think that's the way the development should be done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152176/discussion-between-kfx-and-maximus).

Comment: @kfx I, for one, think that answers that dump code without any explanations are generally undeserving of upvotes, let alone accepting. The accepted answer is *actually helpful*, teaches something. Reading that code here, may or may not solve the specific problem of OP, but is useless for pretty much anyone else.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I wonder if "teaches something, just incorrectly" is really the kind of answers SO should have. To push this further, what would you say about a textbook where the code examples are incorrect and "the solution to fix them is left to the student"?. The system where technically incorrect answers are upvoted de-incentivizes people to do good work in crafting answers, as well as decreases the reputation of StackOverflow in the long term.

Comment: @kfx I believe you are mistaken. While the code example is indeed wrong, the principle expressed is thoroughly valid. Moreover, while I share your ideal of making this the best place possible, this is hardly a high view question, and can suffer the inconsistency while the writer fixes it.